# How to send array number in HTML + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, copy, copy-paste

I couldn't find this because I don't know how to properly word the question so sorry about that.

I'm trying to make a website where you click a button and you get a pop-up with pre-selected text:

```
var text = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
var x;

function copyToClipboard(text[x]) {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

like so. Problem is I don't know how to send the correct array number from the button. Is this possible do I need to compromise and possibly just write several functions deciding what x is?

EDIT: I worded the question wrongly, I want several buttons one that grabs text[1], the other text[2], the next text[3] etc. etc.

So it would be something like:

```
<button id="btn1" onClick="copyToClipboard(1)"></button>
<button id="btn2" onClick="copyToClipboard(2)"></button>
<button id="btn3" onClick="copyToClipboard(3)"></button>
```

EDIT 2: It's been answered and it was way to simple. Sorry for bothering anyone.

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the buttons you're clicking? That, presumably, might give us some information as to which array-element's text should be determined. As it is you've given no information as to what should determine the correct text to show. Please take the time to read both the "*[mcve]*" and the "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: Try `function copyToClipboard( x ) {window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text[x]);}` But you'll have to explain what determines 'x', since as written there's no code shown that sets x to a value. PS: there's methods to directly copy text to the clipboard as well.

Comment: I do not have the HTML code of the buttons since I thought they would just be <button> tags. As for the directly copy text to the clipboard I searched and found that that was considered "unsafe" for many browsers.

Comment: Added how I thought it would kinda look but not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit Simple passe position  to function and then prompt it's value(knowing that the first value statrt from 0 in the array) :

```js
var text = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

function copyToClipboard(x) {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text[x]);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onClick="copyToClipboard(0)" >Btn 1</button>

<button id="btn2" onClick="copyToClipboard(1)" >Btn 2</button>

<button id="btn3" onClick="copyToClipboard(2)" >Btn 3</button>
```

Comment: Wow, i didn't expect that to work nor be that simple. I must've written wrong somewhere when I tried that... Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome :) @JDoawp thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the index matching the value entered in the prompt, you would use the following:

```
var enteredValue = window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
var x = text.indexOf(enteredValue);
```

Comment: I worded my question wrongly and have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I wanted to offer an alternative simply to show an approach that doesn't require the use of in-line JavaScript (which is difficult to maintain, update or change in the future). It also litters event-handlers throughout the code and requires HTML elements to be updated to pass the expected parameters to the named functions, which itself leads to potential problems.

That said, the alternative I'd suggest is as follows:

```js
// the zero-indexed Array of Strings:
var text = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

// the named function:
function copyToClipboard() {
  window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter",

  // here we find the sequence of one, or more, numbers
  // ('\d+') at the end of the String ('$') (derived from
  // the 'id' property of the passed-in the 'this' element,
  // passed automatically from the addEventListener() method)
  //  using a regular expression literal ('/.../');
  // we use the unary '+' operator to convert that numeric
  // String into a real Number and then subtract 1,to move
  // from a one-based index to JavaScript's zero-based index:
  text[ +this.id.match(/\d+$/) - 1 ]);
}

// here we convert the Array-like NodeList (from
// document.querySelectorAll('button') retrieving
// the <button> elements) into an Array using
// Array.prototype.slice() along with
// Function.prototype.call():
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'))
  // we then use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
  // Array of <button> elements:
  .forEach(
    function(button) {
    // 'button' a reference to the current <button> element
    // in the Array of <button> elements over which we're
    // iterating.

    // here we add an event-listener for the 'click' event,
    // binding the copyToClipboard() function as the event-
    // handler for that event (note the deliberate lack of
    // parentheses):
    button.addEventListener('click', copyToClipboard);
  });
```

```html
<!-- note the removal of the 'onclick' event-handlers -->
<button id="btn1">One</button>
<button id="btn2">Two</button>
<button id="btn3">Three</button>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [Guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (MDN).
- [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [Unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()).
- [`Window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I do not understand all of it since I'm not that far into javascript but I wouldn't doubt it'll be useful in the future.